# Siverlight development setup issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, installation

If I am using Windows Vista x86 Enterprise as development environment, and I have installed VSTS 2008 + SP1, .Net 3.5 and I use C#. Any additional SDK/components from Microsoft do you suggest I to setup which are must required?

Too many terms called Siverlight SDK/Plug-in which makes myself headache. Do not know which ones should I install. :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the [Silverlight Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=c22d6a7b-546f-4407-8ef6-d60c8ee221ed)

The [Silverlight site](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/) also has sample downloads, trials of Expression Blend and the bits for DeepZoom, but they're extras and not necessary to get started.

Comment: Cool, my question is answered.